# Data studio: Add a symbol to the calculate metric output

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to add a symbol to my calculate metric that is gonna display as Scorecard on Google data studio

```
(Goal 1 (Goal 1 Completions) / Goal 2: (Goal 2 Completions))
```

The result is a number that is equivalent to a currency, but I would like to add the currency symbol at the end, any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -2):

You need to set the calculated field data type to currency and choose the currency you want.
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9514333